# How to show that $F(s) = E\left ( 1 \left \{ y \leq s \right \} \right )$?

Tags: probability, cumulative-distribution-functions

For any $s$. Here 1 is an indicator function.

Also let $L(y) = F$, where $F$ is a CDF.

My attempt: $$E\left ( 1 \left \{ y \leq s \right \} \right ) = 1 \times P\left ( y \leq s \right ) + 0 \times P\left ( y > s \right ) = P\left ( y\leq s \right ) $$

Then how should I be proceeding??

Comment: You are done! Remember the definition of $F(s)$.

Comment: @Milten Oh I see! $F(s) = P \left ( y \leq s \right )$ by definition?

Comment: Yes. Except I don’t know why you define $L(y)$, which you don’t use again. Is it a standard notation for something?

Comment: @Milten I am not sure if it is a standard notation. It's from the textbook that I am following called "A Primer in Econometric Theory" by John Stachurski.

Comment: Ah okay. Well it doesn’t play a role in the problem anyway.